# Paying gas costs in custom cryptocurrency

Tags: transactions, erc-20, gas, fees, mycrypto

Can you pay transaction fees in an ERC token you generate on a private chain? IE if I make ABC coin, can I pay gas costs in ABC instead of in ETH?

Answer (score 1):

All transaction fees on the Ethereum mainnet must be paid in ETH.

If you create a private chain, you can add the ability to pay transaction fees in ERC20 tokens. However, you will not be able to use this chain or tokens to interact with the Ethereum mainnet.